# python - calculate orthographic similarity between words of a list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-itertools, levenshtein-distance

I need to calculate orthographic similarity (edit/Levenshtein distance) among words in a given corpus.

As Kirill suggested below, I tried to do the following:

```
import csv, itertools, Levenshtein
import numpy as np

# import the list of words from csv file
path = '/Users/my path'
file = path + 'file.csv'

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    wordlist = list(reader)

wordlist = np.array(wordlist) #make it a np array
wordlist2 = wordlist[:,0] #subset the first column of the imported list

for a, b in itertools.product(wordlist, wordlist):
    if a < b:
        print(a, b, Levenshtein.distance(a, b))
```

However, the following error pops up:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I understand the ambiguity in the code, but can someone help me figure out how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do these examples help? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Python

Comment: Regarding your new code, I see this for `test.csv` that contains just `test\n`: `wordlist = list(reader)  # Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)`. So since the stack trace is omitted, your error is not clear. My suggestion is to approach the whole thing step by step: first (using a separate program) prepare a text file that contains just newline-separated words, check the file and then run the code from my answer with `words = sorted(set(s.strip() for s in open(filename))`.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I came up with thank to the help of Kirill.

```
import csv#, StringIO
import itertools, Levenshtein

# open the newline-separated list of words
path = '/Users/your path'
file = path + 'wordlists.txt'
output = path + 'ortho_similarities.txt'
words = sorted(set(s.strip() for s in open(file)))

# the following loop take all possible pairwise combinations
# of the words in the list words, and calculate the LD
# and then let's write everything in a csv file
with open(output, 'wb') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f, delimter=",", lineterminator="\n")
   for a, b in itertools.product(words, words):
      if a < b:
        write.writerow([a, b, Levenshtein.distance(a,b)])
```

Answer (score 4):

Levenshtein distance by its definition can be computed only between two strings: it's how you can edit one string to obtain the other. You can compare words pairwise, it requires `n*(n-1)/2` comparisons (where `n` is the number of unique words in your corpus). Here's how you can do it:

```
>>> import itertools, Levenshtein
>>> words = sorted(set('little Mary had a little lamb'.split()))
>>> for a, b in itertools.product(words, words):
...     if a < b:
...         print(a, b, Levenshtein.distance(a, b))
... 
Mary a 3
Mary had 3
Mary lamb 3
Mary little 6
a had 2
a lamb 3
a little 6
had lamb 3
had little 6
lamb little 5
```

Comment: So if I have a list of words, I should be able to use your code so that the distance is calculated for each of the possible word pairs. Correct?

Comment: @RobertP. Correct.

Comment: Hi @Kirill, I tried to do what you suggested, but I don't seem to make it work - would you mind helping out? See more details in the question.